# Why is the notation $A\setminus B$ preferred over $A-B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, why is the notation  $A\setminus B$ preferred over $A-B$ for set differences?

Comment: The correct notation is rather $A \setminus B$.

Comment: IMO there is no "deep reason" why it is so... Authoritative textbook of 20th Century (Hausdorff, Bourbaki) used the "$-$" sign.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422399/other-than-setminus-and-are-there-any-other-notations-for-the-set-theore)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In some contexts $A-B$ might refer to things like the [Minkowski difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of two subsets of a vector space, like $A+B$ almost always refers to the sum $\{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$.

The notation $A\setminus B$ is less likely to collide with other common interpretations of $A-B$.

Answer (score 3):

Because $A-B$ is ambiguous and could mean $\{a-b:a\in A, b\in B\}$.