# Gamma function minimum and maximum possible Value

Tags: special-functions

Hello everyone I tried to find out the range of $\Gamma$ function but, I didn't .Can anyone please explain the range of $\Gamma$ i.e. the minimum and maximum value of $\Gamma(x)$ of any number $x$.

Comment: Are you referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution, or which?

Comment: No Sir i want to know range of Gamma , Are the range of gamma is (0,Inf) ? or any other interval.with explanation

Comment: You are referring to the Gamma function (generalization of factorial)?

Comment: It seems like multiple people are confused about what you exactly mean by "gamma". Can you link some material that defines what it means?

Comment: yes sir like we find gamma(4)=3!=6 , but i want to know ,what could be the gamma(any number), i.e. range of "Gamma".

Comment: Ah, okay! The fact that you put "statistics" as a tag, confused me!

Comment: Well, obviously since it's essentially the factorial, the gamma function has no upper bound.

Comment: Okay, what about lower bound?

Comment: No lower bound if you consider negative values of $x$. See grphical representation here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function.

Comment: Okay,then I can say values of gamma(Number) lies between (-Inf ,+Inf)?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you mean $\Gamma$ *over the reals*. That range is $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

[image]

Comment: well,you mean the range is    R-{0}

Comment: @user725318: I don't know this notation.

Comment: i mean  range is (   real numbers excluding zero)

Comment: @user725318: check the plot.

Comment: okay sir  thanks

Comment: "I don't know this notation." $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ is another notation for what you've written as $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$. See [Other than $\setminus$ and $-$, are there any other notations for the set-theoretic difference of sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1422399/26369) on MSE or [the Relative Complement section of the Complement page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) on English Wikipedia for some discussion.

Comment: @MarkS.: seems that the OP didn't know the other.